# play framework offline distribution

Tags: java, playframework, frameworks, web

I want to work with play framework in my office. Unfortunately I don't have access to network in my work. I tried to download the play offline distribution but I get an error:

local: tried        D:\Users\dan.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml
unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries

There is a way to run play framework without internet connections?

Answer (score 0):

The first time you run play you need an internet connection in order to resolve all dependencies.

Then, if you want to work offline, you can add

```
offline := true
```

in you build.sbt, this will prevent play from trying to fetch the latest dependencies online and should solve your problem.